# How to pass a variable className to my object function, using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Object-Orientated-Programming. I am trying to pass a element class as a parameter to a function. I know I've missed something...see code below:

```
var n = new Object();

n.mousePosition = function(class, y){   
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        if(e.pageY < y){ $(class).slideDown(200); }
        if(e.pageY > y){ $(class).slideUp(200); }
    });
}
n.mousePosition('.nav', 100);
```

The `.nav` is the element class name which I'm trying to pass to my function as the `class` parameter, the `$(class).slideDown...` is not picking it up

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: `class` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in JavaScript, what happens if you use a different variable name (`elemClass`, for example)?

Comment: No worries, that was the central theme of several answers, below, too. So if it's solved, you should accept one of those =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class is a reserved keyword in JavaScript. Use something different, e.g. className as parameter name instead.

Answer (score 1):

`Class` is a reserved word, preface it with something else to avoid that issue, ie... `myClass`.

In addition you don't *need* to preface the `class` with the . when passing it in as a parameter.

```
n.mousePosition('nav', 100);
```

Comment: but then he will need to add a dot(.) in the function, best is to pass `.nav` because later on it can be changed to some other selector

Comment: +1 for reserved word, -1 because jQuery is being used, so yes he does need to prefix the className with `.`

Comment: @AaronMcIver thanks for your input. DavidThomas's comment did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Note that `class` is a reserved word:

```
function t(class) }
    console.log(class);
}

t("test")
```

Result (Firefox 8.0):

> SyntaxError: class is a reserved identifier

Try renaming to `className` (or similar).

The more **general advice** I'd give is that you could have easily caught this error by running the snippet in Firebug or jsfiddle or by debugging in some other environment that would have exposed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Class is a reserved word in JavaScript. You cannot use class as a variable name. For other reserved words you can visit: http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a reserved keyword use something else e.g. `klass`

```
var n = new Object();

n.mousePosition = function(klass, y){   
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        if(e.pageY < y){ $(klass).slideDown(200); }
        if(e.pageY > y){ $(klass).slideUp(200); }
    });
}
n.mousePosition('.nav', 100);
```

see jsfiddle example in action http://jsfiddle.net/anuraguniyal/LBfBn/4/